# Upgraded HP Pavilion G7 1317cl with Bios vers F45 to 8GB only 3.3GB recognised in Ubuntu 12.04 X64

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, ram, hp-pavilion

Bios and hardware probes indicate 8GB installed. Swapped chip slots with no difference in behavior. DMESG E820 map as follows:

```
BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 0000000000000000 - 000000000009f800 (usable)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 000000000009f800 - 00000000000a0000 (reserved)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 00000000000e0000 - 0000000000100000 (reserved)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 0000000000100000 - 00000000bf9bf000 (usable)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 00000000bf9bf000 - 00000000bfabf000 (reserved)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 00000000bfabf000 - 00000000bfbbf000 (ACPI NVS)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 00000000bfbbf000 - 00000000bfbf5000 (ACPI data)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 00000000bfbf5000 - 00000000bfc00000 (usable)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 00000000bfc00000 - 00000000e0000000 (reserved)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 00000000f8000000 - 00000000fc000000 (reserved)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 00000000fec00000 - 00000000fec01000 (reserved)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 00000000fec10000 - 00000000fec11000 (reserved)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 00000000fed80000 - 00000000fed81000 (reserved)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 00000000fee00000 - 00000000fee01000 (reserved)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 00000000ffe00000 - 0000000100000000 (reserved)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 0000000100000000 - 000000011f000000 (usable)
[    0.000000] NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
[    0.000000] DMI 2.7 present.
[    0.000000] DMI: Hewlett-Packard HP Pavilion g7 Notebook PC/3568, BIOS F.45 01/17/2012
[    0.000000] e820 update range: 0000000000000000 - 0000000000010000 (usable) ==> (reserved)
[    0.000000] e820 remove range: 00000000000a0000 - 0000000000100000 (usable)
```

Comment: Bios memory tests also good regardless of which memory card is in which position but does not report how much memory was tested. Live Ubuntu X64 CD gives same outcome. Ubuntu system report fails for memory with 43% difference between installed and tested. Any help out there?

Comment: Replaced entire rig with matched 4GB pair and still have the same results. Is anyone out there? My next effort will be a Windows 7 install to a spare HDD to validate hardware or OS issue.

Answer (score 1):

Upgraded Bios to ver F.52 - no help. Re-installed Windows 7 with same symptoms. Returned laptop as bad system memory slot 2. As an aside, HP was incredibly not helpful and the 90 day return policy from the retailer was my best option for resolving the issue with an entirely new laptop.

Comment: Hi Lyle, if you should ever come back, please accept your answer!